# Annoying adverts showing on top of other apps

Tags: applications, huawei, ads

On my sister's Huawei 360 adverts appear on top of other applications whenever wifi or mobile data connectivity is on. These adverts are so annoying since the sometimes freeze the phone covering the whole screen with a small x on the right hand side corner. They also consume a lot of data. They can show even on whatsapp.
I have checked if there are any launchers but only the default one appers, Also I dont any funny apps in data usage under apps that use background data. Could these apps be the one installed via USSD code or phone serial number?

Comment: It's quite difficult to answer, without having knowledge of your installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason for these annoying ads might be because of your browser when you have accidentally clicked on any of adds shown.Those malicious adds may install some apps in your **ROM(internal memory)** which may not be uninstalled so easily or will re-appear every time you connect to internet.
So, you could take backup and restore the phone to factory settings.
I did the same way when i was attacked by these malicious apps.

**PS:** these type of apps may import your photographs and other data. Please be cautious and do factory setting ASAP.

Comment: Notice that **ROM** is another way to call the **firmware**, or **operating system**. If those advertising applications pushed themselves to the **/system** partition of a device, then a mere factory reset won't help.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman How would one go around that then? Would it involve installing a custom rom?

Comment: @user145490 There are three ways around privileged ads. The first involves rooting the phone, manually identifying the offending apps, searching for their packages inside **/system/app** or **/system/priv-app** and delete them (tedious, but less aggressive). The second is to try finding your device's stock ROM, and flash it. The third is similar to the second, but is about flashing a custom ROM, yes.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I would not recommend the first one, as you can really screw up your OS (and maybe notice that too late) when deleting the wrong files with root

Comment: @Namnodorel And that sums up pretty well why root tends to be disabled by default, doesn't it? One should _always_ make backups before toying, and _always_ inform themselves before deleting or messing with something unknown. Root is powerful, but that power is not without risk.